# Why do I get a certificate error trying to setup a Ubuntu Cloud?

Tags: linux, certificate, cloud, ubuntu-11.04

I'm trying to install an Ubuntu cloud on my home network - I've been following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC/CDInstall).

When I arrived at *STEP 6: Install an image from the store PART 3: Click on the Store tab* I get the following error message on the page:

> Error 60: server certificate verification failed. CAfile:
>   /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

There seems to be something wrong with the certificate but I have no idea how to solve this, help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quick and insecure fix**
WARNING: the change disables certificate validation. Use at your own risk!!

Until PycURL is fixed you can edit file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imagestore/lib/fetch.py
on fetch method after the line 142
add

```
curl.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
curl.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)
```

Restart the image-store-proxy

And also update godaddy certificates for wget and alike:

```
sudo wget -P /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ --no-check-certificate   
https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/gd-class2-root.crt https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/gd_intermediate.crt https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/gd_cross_intermediate.crt
sudo  update-ca-certificates
```